# Was this question really a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question about [PowerMockito .when().thenReturn() with randomUUID not returning expected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44829909/powermockito-when-thenreturn-with-randomuuid-not-returning-expected-value) 4 days ago, I got a Java gold badge user vote to close as a duplicate from another question (which I linked in the body of my question and explained what happened when I tried the accepted answer in the question), however I want to try the answers in my question and probably one of them will provide an answer to the question, which in the comments another user said that:

> It seems that various and not necessarily correct info is circulating about this issue, which seems to include some confusion even from PowerMock contributor's side

I can't try the answers in my question yet, due to some technical issues in the remote pc I'm working with, but I want to try the answers in my question  as the question seems to be a common problem that hasn't got many good answers out there yet...

I also left a comment in the question to the user who closed it, and there seem to be other (2) users that agree that the question is not a duplicate, but maybe some more experienced users agree with the user that closed it or with me, so, I would like to know so I can improve the question (if possible) so it doesn't seem like a duplicate or if it is, know what (or how) could have I searched better in order to prevent it. Since I believe that I provided enough research links and explained what didn't work when I tried those solutions, and my question was not a generic one, but a specific one.

I waited until now, because I think 4 days was enough time for the review queue to agree or disagree with the closure, but since it hasn't got any new votes to reopen nor the ones that existed have dissapeared, I would like to know more about your opinions

Comment: Erm, wait, you have no idea whether the answers solve your problem, yet you want the question to be re-opened anyway?  How is that sensible?

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for your reply, I already tried one of the answers right now, sorry for late reply but as I said I was trying to solve some technical issues first, I was just asking if the question was really a duplicate, in this case Makoto's answer is (IMO) what I was looking for. Thank you, I'll be sure to check all answers first next time before posting on meta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You're right** that the dupe didn't answer your question, as the solution you received was less than satisfactory.

**However**, that doesn't mean that this knowledge should be so fragmented.  I've added an answer to your question which should address your issue in the duplicate.  It's better served there since we'll likely have more people looking for the generic approach to mocking out UUIDs instead of a more localized approach.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be sure to upvote it too so it raises a little on that question. I also accepted one of the answers in my question, as it solved it correctly